# Programmatically changing system-wide speaker balance on Windows 7

Tags: python, windows, audio, windows-7

How can I programmatically change system-wide speaker balance on Windows 7?

(I can only program in Python and AHK.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Shortcut(created by @AndreMiras)  --> use [Pycaw](https://github.com/AndreMiras/pycaw) , usage of Pycaw can be find [here](https://github.com/AndreMiras/pycaw#usage)

Detailed way -- > First install python package Comtypes either by

1. using *pip install comtypes*

   or
2. download from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/comtypes and then extract the download folder. Find setup.py in extracted folder . Open cmd go to the path of *setup.py* and then run the command *python setup.py install*

Now just run the code.py file and you can adjust the volume by changing the first argument of function **SetMasterVolumeLevel(*-25*, None)** the first argument must be in between  -65 to 0.
I have tried this code in windows 8 hopefully it will work on windows 7.

See at the last lines of code to find the **volume.SetMasterVolumeLevel(-25, None)** and to adust the volume of PC

Code.py

```
from comtypes import *
import comtypes.client
from ctypes import POINTER
from ctypes.wintypes import DWORD, BOOL

MMDeviceApiLib = \
    GUID('{2FDAAFA3-7523-4F66-9957-9D5E7FE698F6}')
IID_IMMDevice = \
    GUID('{D666063F-1587-4E43-81F1-B948E807363F}')
IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator = \
    GUID('{A95664D2-9614-4F35-A746-DE8DB63617E6}')
CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator = \
    GUID('{BCDE0395-E52F-467C-8E3D-C4579291692E}')
IID_IMMDeviceCollection = \
    GUID('{0BD7A1BE-7A1A-44DB-8397-CC5392387B5E}')
IID_IAudioEndpointVolume = \
    GUID('{5CDF2C82-841E-4546-9722-0CF74078229A}')

class IMMDeviceCollection(IUnknown):
    _iid_ = GUID('{0BD7A1BE-7A1A-44DB-8397-CC5392387B5E}')
    pass

class IAudioEndpointVolume(IUnknown):
    _iid_ = GUID('{5CDF2C82-841E-4546-9722-0CF74078229A}')
    _methods_ = [
        STDMETHOD(HRESULT, 'RegisterControlChangeNotify', []),
        STDMETHOD(HRESULT, 'UnregisterControlChangeNotify', []),
        STDMETHOD(HRESULT, 'GetChannelCount', []),
        COMMETHOD([], HRESULT, 'SetMasterVolumeLevel',
            (['in'], c_float, 'fLevelDB'),
            (['in'], POINTER(GUID), 'pguidEventContext')
        ),
        COMMETHOD([], HRESULT, 'SetMasterVolumeLevelScalar',
            (['in'], c_float, 'fLevelDB'),
            (['in'], POINTER(GUID), 'pguidEventContext')
        ),
        COMMETHOD([], HRESULT, 'GetMasterVolumeLevel',
            (['out','retval'], POINTER(c_float), 'pfLevelDB')
        ),
        COMMETHOD([], HRESULT, 'GetMasterVolumeLevelScalar',
            (['out','retval'], POINTER(c_float), 'pfLevelDB')
        ),
        COMMETHOD([], HRESULT, 'SetChannelVolumeLevel',
            (['in'], DWORD, 'nChannel'),
            (['in'], c_float, 'fLevelDB'),
            (['in'], POINTER(GUID), 'pguidEventContext')
        ),
        COMMETHOD([], HRESULT, 'SetChannelVolumeLevelScalar',
            (['in'], DWORD, 'nChannel'),
            (['in'], c_float, 'fLevelDB'),
            (['in'], POINTER(GUID), 'pguidEventContext')
        ),
        COMMETHOD([], HRESULT, 'GetChannelVolumeLevel',
            (['in'], DWORD, 'nChannel'),
            (['out','retval'], POINTER(c_float), 'pfLevelDB')
        ),
        COMMETHOD([], HRESULT, 'GetChannelVolumeLevelScalar',
            (['in'], DWORD, 'nChannel'),
            (['out','retval'], POINTER(c_float), 'pfLevelDB')
        ),
        COMMETHOD([], HRESULT, 'SetMute',
            (['in'], BOOL, 'bMute'),
            (['in'], POINTER(GUID), 'pguidEventContext')
        ),
        COMMETHOD([], HRESULT, 'GetMute',
            (['out','retval'], POINTER(BOOL), 'pbMute')
        ),
        COMMETHOD([], HRESULT, 'GetVolumeStepInfo',
            (['out','retval'], POINTER(c_float), 'pnStep'),
            (['out','retval'], POINTER(c_float), 'pnStepCount'),
        ),
        COMMETHOD([], HRESULT, 'VolumeStepUp',
            (['in'], POINTER(GUID), 'pguidEventContext')
        ),
        COMMETHOD([], HRESULT, 'VolumeStepDown',
            (['in'], POINTER(GUID), 'pguidEventContext')
        ),
        COMMETHOD([], HRESULT, 'QueryHardwareSupport',
            (['out','retval'], POINTER(DWORD), 'pdwHardwareSupportMask')
        ),
        COMMETHOD([], HRESULT, 'GetVolumeRange',
            (['out','retval'], POINTER(c_float), 'pfMin'),
            (['out','retval'], POINTER(c_float), 'pfMax'),
            (['out','retval'], POINTER(c_float), 'pfIncr')
        ),

    ]

class IMMDevice(IUnknown):
    _iid_ = GUID('{D666063F-1587-4E43-81F1-B948E807363F}')
    _methods_ = [
        COMMETHOD([], HRESULT, 'Activate',
            (['in'], POINTER(GUID), 'iid'),
            (['in'], DWORD, 'dwClsCtx'),
            (['in'], POINTER(DWORD), 'pActivationParans'),
            (['out','retval'], POINTER(POINTER(IAudioEndpointVolume)), 'ppInterface')
        ),
        STDMETHOD(HRESULT, 'OpenPropertyStore', []),
        STDMETHOD(HRESULT, 'GetId', []),
        STDMETHOD(HRESULT, 'GetState', [])
    ]
    pass

class IMMDeviceEnumerator(comtypes.IUnknown):
    _iid_ = GUID('{A95664D2-9614-4F35-A746-DE8DB63617E6}')

    _methods_ = [
        COMMETHOD([], HRESULT, 'EnumAudioEndpoints',
            (['in'], DWORD, 'dataFlow'),
            (['in'], DWORD, 'dwStateMask'),
            (['out','retval'], POINTER(POINTER(IMMDeviceCollection)), 'ppDevices')
        ),
        COMMETHOD([], HRESULT, 'GetDefaultAudioEndpoint',
            (['in'], DWORD, 'dataFlow'),
            (['in'], DWORD, 'role'),
            (['out','retval'], POINTER(POINTER(IMMDevice)), 'ppDevices')
        )
    ]





enumerator = comtypes.CoCreateInstance( 
    CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator,
    IMMDeviceEnumerator,
    comtypes.CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER
)

print enumerator
endpoint = enumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint( 0, 1 )
print endpoint
volume = endpoint.Activate( IID_IAudioEndpointVolume, comtypes.CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, None )
print volume
print volume.GetMasterVolumeLevel()
print volume.GetVolumeRange()
#volume.SetMasterVolumeLevel(-65, None) uncomment for 0 volume
#volume.SetMasterVolumeLevel(-1, None) uncomment for full volume
volume.SetMasterVolumeLevel(-25, None) #Change the first argument for controlling the volume remember it should be -ve not less than -65
```

Comment: 1. That's amazing. 2. How do I make it change balance rather than just volume? This is what the question is about.

Comment: You can change the balance of speakers with SetChannelVolumeLevel(0,-65,None) function. 
Goto the last line of code and add the following line to it : volume.SetChannelVolumeLevel(0,-30,None)
you can change the second argument for adjusting the balance the range is from 0 to -65

Comment: That's it, well done! I've created a Python library https://github.com/AndreMiras/pycaw

Comment: @AndreMiras Nicely Done

Comment: Is there any way to unmute the volume?

Comment: @VladimirShevyakov You can use `volume.SetMasterVolumeLevel(-1, None)`  for full volume. Its just a hack not a full solutions.Check if it works for you. :)

Comment: @AndreMiras We all appreciate your amazing work! But is there anyway to change the volume of an *ENDPOINT* by percents and not by decimals?

Comment: Thanks @DanielReyhanian for the support. That should be doable via `SetMasterVolumeLevelScalar()`, see https://github.com/AndreMiras/pycaw/issues/13

Comment: @AndreMiras Amazing work! Thanks a lot. We owe you big time.